# DB2 IMPORT characters replaced

Tags: import, db2

When you run the following command .

```
IMPORT FROM D:\CSV\detdatboo.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY CODEPAGE=1252 \
nodoubledel MESSAGES D:\CSV\DUMP\90detdatboo.txt INSERT INTO SGC1."detdatboo"
```

The imported data in the case of the following characters (° ó ñ ú á ) are replaced by these other ( Â° Ã³ Ã± Ãº Ã¡ ) respectively.
The version of DB2 is v10.5.500.107 CODEPAGE = 1252.

Comment: Is your input file really in the CP1252 code set? It looks like it may be in Unicode.

Comment: Thanks!!, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will also say the input file codepage is not 1252. you can read more about codepage and DB2 [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html?lang=en)